# React issue with state variables - Number Vs String

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am facing this weird issue as explained below.

I have defined some constants as :

```
const HIGH_YIELD = 0, LEAST_RISKY = 1, FAIR_PRICED = 2;
```

then initializing in my constructor:

```
this.state = { data: [], errors: {}, subscription: {}, sort: HIGH_YIELD};
```

Now within the same constructor if I use it like this:

```
switch(this.state.sort){
     case HIGH_YIELD: {this.state.subscription.sort = 'highyield'; break;}
     case LEAST_RISKY: {this.state.subscription.sort = 'leastrisky'; break;}
     case FAIR_PRICED: {this.state.subscription.sort = 'fairpriced'; break;}
     default: {console.log('sortdddd'); break;}
 }
```

it works fine, but in my componentDidUpdate, the same switch doesn't work and it always falls to default case. I am using below code to render a native select using material UI:

```
<NativeSelect value={sort} onChange={this.handleSort} >
     <option value={HIGH_YIELD}>High Yielding</option>
     <option value={LEAST_RISKY}>Less Risky</option>
     <option value={FAIR_PRICED}>Fairly Priced</option>
 </NativeSelect>
```

and my handleSort simply does

```
this.setState({sort: event.target.value})
```

Now if I change the constants like this

```
const HIGH_YIELD = '0', LEAST_RISKY = '1', FAIR_PRICED = '2';
```

then everything works fine - including the constructor code and the componentDidUpdate method.

Any clue why this should happen? Is this issue with React or material-ui?

Comment: Show us the handleSort and componentDidUpdate code. There might be mistake, I assume.

Comment: Option values are always strings. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement